# Use of <%= %> and <%# %> for server control

Tags: asp.net

How i can use of  "<%= %> and <%# %>" for server control?I try use of "<%= %> and <%# %>"
in a LinkButton(Like below tag a) ,but i get this Error "Invalid expression term '>'",
but tag a was without Error?

```
<a title='<%#Eval("Title")%>' href="<%="WebForm6.aspx?ID="%><%#Eval("News_ID")%>">content</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant use **inside as internal attribute**  a server tag <%....

what you can do is :

make it a server side control and in **ItemDataBount** Event - to **findControl** using **Id** and then **set its attributes**.

Comment: hi Mid787, I solve my problem:
    <asp:LinkButton Text='<%#Eval("Title")%>' PostBackUrl="~/WebForm6.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("News_ID")%>" runat="server" />

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the href attribut in ' iinstead of "